# Route::controller route names

Tags: routes, laravel-5.1

How can I get route names for `Route::controller` to use with `route()` helper ?

For example:

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

Is possible to use 'admin' as a prefix, for example `route('admin.users')` and so on ?

I've tried issuing `artisan route:list` but doesn't show anything for these routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'as' to specify names for your routes,

```
Route::get('/admin/users', [
    'as' => 'admin.users', 'uses' => 'AdminController@users'
]);
```

Now if you see the output of artisan `route:list` You should see the name of the route /admin/users is set to admin.users

Comment: I don't want to write a route for each view, for this I've used `Route::controller`

Comment: Then you could try this

`Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController', [
        'getUsers' => 'admin.users',
    ]);`

Comment: it helps, map manually only the essential routes. But, there's no official way to add a prefix-like to `Route::controller` so each route like `/admin/users` get mapped to `admin.users` ?, if this is true I'll accept your answer